# Answers > Views?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Unless I am missing something, shouldn't the number of views be greater than or equal to the number of answers or votes? Hmmmm.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is normal. The number of views is cached (i.e. stored locally, not retrieved from the database each time) for performance reasons. This effect is much more exaggerated when the site's traffic is low (i.e. like during beta). You will hardly notice the effect when the site is fully launched.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks!